# How do you determine if a Path object is a file or a directory?

Tags: java, path

In the for loop: How do I determine the type of each instance of Path?

```
package grep;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Grep {
    public static void grep(String filePath) throws IOException {
        Path myPath = Paths.get(filePath);
        try (Stream<Path> entries = Files.list(myPath)) 
        {
            List<Path> paths = entries.collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (Path path : paths) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), you can use [`Path#toFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--), and then check if the file is a directory with [`File#isDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory--).

```
for (Path path : paths) {
    if (path.toFile().isDirectory()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or even simpler with [`Files#isDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-):

```
for (Path path : paths) {
    if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Rarely, use this API but any specific reason we have to invoke `toFile()` instead of just `Files.isDirectory(file);` or
`Files.isRegularFile(file);` ?

Comment: @Aominè Just thought of it right before you commented, thanks though :)